# Remove hyphenation for all document

Tags: spelling

I have the following WME:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %son yükle


% BEGIN
\begin{document}

  % CHAPTER 1
  \chapter{GİRİŞ}
  \lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

I want to disable all hyphenation in the document. How can i do that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That is not spelling, that is called hyphenation, you might want to rephrase your title.

Comment: @daleif Oh i used wrong word, thank you for warning (:

Comment: Your best bet is probably `\raggedright`, but that will remove paragraph indentation as well (it can be reintroduced manually) . Why do you want to remove hyphernation?

Comment: `\hyphenpenalty=10000` perhaps?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen too slow :(

Comment: don't destroy main features of tex! you can minimize number of hyphenation with use of `microtype` package. however you can use left aligned text by add `\raggedright` at begin of text.

Comment: @daleif My thesis writing guide tells to not use hyphernation.

Comment: Astounding. But then you *need* something like raggedright, or the result will be truly horrible.

Comment: @volkan sigh written with Word in mind?

Comment: @daleif Sorry, my English is not very well. I don't understand what do you want to tell when saying "sigh written with Word in mind?"?

Comment: @volkan it was just a comment about the guidelines you are forced to use. Often they are written with the program Word in mind, and thus does not make sense when combined with a system with better typographical capabilities

Comment: @daleif Oh yes, probably it is written for MS Word users. When i examine the written thesis, realy there is no hyphenation use.

Comment: \hyphenpenalty=10000 @HaraldHanche-Olsen I used this command but some lines extended.

Comment: @daleif \raggedright is not inappropriate. :/

Comment: Yes, that will happen. It has to be supplemented by a bunch of changes to various parameters governing the line breaking process. The result will be many extremely large interword spaces, will terrible results.

Comment: @volkan not understood?

Comment: Double negations are tricky. Ask Donald Trump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} %son yükle


\begin{document}
\sloppy

\chapter{GİRİŞ}

İstanbul, Türkiye'de yer alan şehir ve ülkenin 81 ilinden biri. Ülkenin en kalabalık, ekonomik, tarihi ve sosyo-kültürel açıdan en önemli şehridir. Şehir, iktisadi büyüklük açısından dünyada 34., nüfus açısından belediye sınırları göz önüne alınarak yapılan sıralamaya göre Avrupa'da birinci, dünyada ise Lagos'tan sonra altıncı sırada yer almaktadır.

İstanbul Türkiye'nin kuzeybatısında, Marmara kıyısı ve Boğaziçi boyunca, Haliç'i de çevreleyecek şekilde kurulmuştur. İstanbul kıtalararası bir şehir olup, Avrupa'daki bölümüne Avrupa Yakası veya Rumeli Yakası, Asya'daki bölümüne ise Anadolu Yakası veya Asya Yakası denir. Tarihte ilk olarak üç tarafı Marmara Denizi, Boğaziçi ve Haliç'in sardığı bir yarımada üzerinde kurulan İstanbul'un batıdaki sınırını İstanbul Surları oluşturmaktaydı. Gelişme ve büyüme sürecinde surların her seferinde daha batıya ilerletilerek inşa edilmesiyle 4 defa genişletilen şehrin 39 ilçesi vardır. Sınırları içerisinde ise büyükşehir belediyesi ile birlikte toplam 40 belediye bulunmaktadır.

Dünyanın en eski şehirlerinden biri olan İstanbul, 330-395 yılları arasında Roma İmparatorluğu, 395-1204 ile 1261-1453 yılları arasında Bizans İmparatorluğu, 1204-1261 arasında Latin İmparatorluğu ve son olarak 1453-1922 yılları arasında Osmanlı İmparatorluğu'na başkentlik yaptı. Ayrıca İstanbul, Hilâfetin Osmanlı İmparatorluğu'na geçtiği 1517'den kaldırıldığı 1924'e kadar İslam'ın da merkezi oldu.

Son yıllarda birbiri ardına ortaya çıkartılan arkeolojik bulgularla insanlık tarihine ilişkin önemli bilgiler elde edilmiştir. Yarımburgaz Mağarası'ndan çıkarılan taş aletlerle, ilkel insan izlerinin 400.000 yıl öncesine dayandığı ortaya çıkmıştır. Anadolu Yakası'nda yürütülen kazı çalışmaları ve bunlara bağlı araştırmalar, şehirde tarım ve hayvancılığa dayalı ilk yerleşik insan topluluğunun MÖ 5500'lere tarihlenen Fikirtepe Kültürü olduğunu göstermiştir. Bu arkeolojik bulgular yalnızca İstanbul'un değil, tüm Marmara Bölgesi'nin en eski insan izleridir. İstanbul sınırları içinde kent bazında ilk yerleşimler ise Anadolu Yakası'nda Kalkedon; Avrupa Yakası'nda Byzantion'dur. Cumhuriyet dönemi öncesinde egemenliği altında olduğu devletlere yüzlerce yıl başkentlik yapan İstanbul, 13 Ekim 1923 tarihinde başkentin Ankara'ya taşınmasıyla bu özelliğini yitirmiş; ancak ülkenin ticaret, sanayi, ulaşım, turizm, eğitim, kültür ve sanat merkezi olma özelliğini sürdüregelmiştir.

Karadeniz ile Marmara Denizi'ni bağlayan ve Asya ile Avrupa'yı ayıran İstanbul Boğazı'na ev sahipliği yapması nedeniyle, İstanbul'un jeopolitik önemi oldukça yüksektir. Bugün tamamına yakını doldurulmuş olan ya da kaybolan doğal limanları vardır. Bu özellikleri yüzünden bölge toprakları üzerinde uzun süreli egemenlik anlaşmazlıkları ve savaşlar yaşanmıştır. Başlıca akarsular Riva, Kâğıthane ve Alibey dereleridir. İl toprakları az engebelidir ve en yüksek noktası Kartal ilçesindeki Aydos Tepesi'dir. İldeki başlıca doğal göller Büyükçekmece, Küçükçekmece ve Durusu gölleridir. İl ve yakın çevresinde, Karadeniz ile Akdeniz makro iklimleri arasında geçiş özellikleri görülür. Hava sıcaklıkları ve yağış ortalamaları düzensiz; bitki örtüsü dengesizdir.

İstanbul'un, Türkiye Büyük Millet Meclisi'nde, 6 Mart 2008 tarihinde kabul edilen ve 22 Mart 2008 tarihli Resmî Gazete'de yayımlanan 5747 sayılı yasa uyarınca 39 ilçesi vardır. Bunlardan 25'i Avrupa Yakası'nda; 14'ü ise Anadolu Yakası'nda bulunur. İlçe belediyeleri bünyesinde toplam 782 mahalle, 152 köy vardır. Tüm ilçeler, 22 Temmuz 2004 tarihinde Resmî Gazete'de yayınlanan yasayla İstanbul Büyükşehir Belediyesi hizmet alanı içine dâhil edilmiştir. Yapılan düzenlemeyle il sınırları içindeki tüm belde belediyeleri de feshedilmiştir.

Osmanlı İmparatorluğu'nda İstanbul Vilayeti'nde idari bölünme oldukça karmaşık ve düzensizdi. Kimi önemli şehirler sınırları içinde olduğu eyalete değil, doğrudan başkent İstanbul'a bağlı olurlardı. İstanbul Vilayeti ise Kandıra, Adapazarı, İznik, Mudanya, Gemlik, Yalova, Orhaneli, Bandırma, Çorlu ve Kıyıköy gibi yerleri de kapsamaktaydı. Yüzyıllar boyunca bu sistemle yönetilen İstanbul'da merkezî yönetimin bölünmesi için ilk girişim 1839 yılında yayınlanan Gülhane Hatt-ı Hümayunu'ndan sonra oldu. Bu dönemde ilk kez Fransa idari bölünme sistemi örnek alınarak İstanbul'da reformlar yapıldı.

Şehrin belediyeler bazında idari bölünmesi, imparatorluk yıkılana dek pek çok kez değişikliğe uğradı. Vilayet dönem dönem günümüzde ilçe belediyeleri olarak adlandırılabilecek dairelere ayrıldı. Bu dairelerin sayısı ve sınırları, ekonomik nedenlerle zaman zaman kapatılmak ya da yeni oluşturulmak suretiyle değişti. Cumhuriyet dönemindeyse, yapılan ilk düzenlemelerde Anadolu Yakası'nda Üsküdar adında yeni bir il oluşturularak, İstanbul günümüz Avrupa Yakası topraklarıyla sınırlandırıldı. Daha sonra Üsküdar ve kendisine bağlı birimler İstanbul'a katıldı.

1950'lere gelindiğinde İstanbul'un iki yakada toplam 16 ilçesi vardı. Bunlardan merkeze bağlı olarak yönetilenler: Eminönü, Fatih, Bakırköy, Beyoğlu, Beşiktaş, Sarıyer, Beykoz, Üsküdar, Kadıköy ve Adalar; il belediye sınırı dışında kalanlarsa Çatalca, Silivri, Şile, Kartal ve Yalova'ydı. Bu düzen, 1980 yılına dek fazla değişiklik göstermeden sürdü. Bu tarihten sonra 3030 sayılı yasayla İstanbul'da yeni ilçeler oluşturulmaya başlandı. 1990'a gelindiğinde İstanbul'un 25 ilçesi bulunuyordu. Yıllar içinde yeni ilçeler oluşturulmaya devam ederken, hızla gelişen ve İstanbul'la kara sınırı bulunmayan Yalova, merkeze uzaklığının sorun olması nedeniyle 1995 yılında Kocaeli ve Bursa illerinden de toprak alınarak ayrı bir il hâline getirildi. İstanbul'un ilçe sayısı 2008 yılında 32'ydi.

Nüfusu 13 milyona yaklaşan İstanbul'da var olan ilçeleri bölerek yeni belediyeler oluşturma fikri yeniden ortaya atıldı. Bunun sonucunda, Büyükşehir Belediyesi sınırları içinde yeni ilçeler oluşturmak için hazırlanan 5747 sayılı yasayla, 2008 yılında İstanbul'un Anadolu Yakasında 3, Avrupa Yakası'ndaysa 5 olmak üzere toplam 8 yeni ilçe kurulurken, Eminönü ilçesi feshedilerek Fatih'e katıldı. İstanbul'da kurulan son ilçeler: Arnavutköy, Ataşehir, Başakşehir, Beylikdüzü, Çekmeköy, Esenyurt, Sancaktepe ve Sultangazi'dir.

İstanbul, Türkiye'nin en büyük şehri ve siyasi olarak eski başkentidir. Kara ve deniz ticaret yollarının bir kavşağı olması ve stratejik konumu nedeniyle Türkiye'de ekonomik yaşamın merkezi olmuştur. Şehir aynı zamanda en büyük sanayi merkezidir. Türkiye'deki sanayi istihdamının %20'sini karşılamaktadır. Yaklaşık olarak %38'lik endüstriyel alana sahiptir. İstanbul ve çevre iller bu alanda; meyve, zeytinyağı, İpek, pamuk ve tütün gibi ürünler elde etmektedir. Ayrıca gıda sanayi, tekstil üretimi, petrol ürünleri, kauçuk, metal eşya, deri, kimya, ilaç, elektronik, cam, teknolojik ürünler, makine, otomotiv, ulaşım araçları, kâğıt ve kâğıt ürünleri ve alkollü içkiler, kentin önemli sanayi ürünleri arasında yer almaktadır. Forbes Dergisi'nin yaptığı araştırmaya göre 2008 yılı Mart itibarıyla 35 milyardere sahip şehir dünya sıralamasında dördüncü olmuştur. Brookings Institution ve JP Morgan'ın 2014 yılı baz alınarak oluşturulan ekonomide yükselen kentler sıralamasında İstanbul 300 şehir arasında İzmir'in ardından 3. sırayı aldı. İstanbul 2013'teki listede 52. sırada yer almaktaydı. Aynı listede Türkiye'den İstanbul ve İzmir dışında Bursa 4 ve Ankara 9. sırada yer almıştır. Yine bu rapora göre İstanbul'daki 2014 yılındaki işsizlik oranı %6,5 olarak gerçekleşmiştir.

İstanbul'da ilk olarak 1866 yılında hizmete giren Dersaadet Tahvilat Borsası, 1986 yılı başlarında mevcut yapı değiştirilerek bugünkü İstanbul Menkul Kıymetler Borsası (İMKB) açılmıştır. 19. ve 20. yüzyıl başlarında Galata semtinde bulunan Bankalar Caddesi Osmanlı İmparatorluğu için finans merkezi olmuştur. Bu bölgede Osmanlı'nın merkez bankası olan Bank-ı Osmanî (1856 yılından sonra yeniden düzenlerek 1863 yılından itibaren Bank-ı Osmanî-i Şahane) ve Osmanlı Borsası bulunurdu. Bankalar Caddesi, 1990 yılına kadar finans ve ekonomi merkezi olmayı korumuş fakat yenileşme hareketi başlaması sonucu modern iş merkezleri Levent ve Maslak bölgeleri olmuştur. 1995 yılında İMKB, Sarıyer'in İstinye semtinde bulunan bugünkü binasına taşınmıştır.

Günümüzde İstanbul, Türkiye'nin %55 üretimine ve %45'lik ticaret hacmine sahiptir. Ülkede Gayrisafi millî hasıla'nın %21.2'lik kısmını oluşturur. Toplam ihracattaki payı %45,2, ithalâttaki payı ise %52,2'dir.

Hemen hemen İstanbul'daki tüm özel lise ve üniversitelerde İngilizce, Fransızca ve Almanca gibi ana yabancı dil veya ikincil yabancı dil eğitimi verilmektedir. Galatasaray Lisesi, 1481 yılında Galata Sarayı Enderun-u Hümayunu adıyla kurulmuştur. Daha sonraki adıyla Galatasaray Mekteb-i Sultanisi şehrin en eski lisesi olmakla birlikte, en eski ikinci eğitim veren kurumudur. Fransızca eğitim vermektedir. 1884 yılında kurulan İstanbul Lisesi daha çok bilinen adıyla İstanbul Erkek Lisesi, uluslararası alanda tanınmış en eski liselerden biridir. Almanca eğitim vermektedir. Kadıköy Anadolu Lisesi eski ve daha iyi bilinen adıyla Kadıköy Maarif Koleji, genç cumhuriyete yön verecek üst düzey eğitimli siyasetçi, bilim adamı ve sanatçılar yetiştirmek amacıyla, Bakanlar Kurulu ve Meclis kararıyla 1955 yılında kurulmuştur. İngilizce eğitim vermektedir. Nişantaşı Anadolu Lisesi, 1905 yılında English High School for Boys adıyla özellikle İngiliz topluluğu mensuplarının çocuklarına sağlıklı bir eğitim vermek amacıyla kurulmuştur. 1979 yılında MEB'e bağlanmış ve şimdiki adını almıştır. Cağaloğlu Anadolu Lisesi, (eski adıyla İstanbul Kız Lisesi) 1850 yılında I.Abdülmecit'in annesi Bezmiâlem Valide Sultan'ın isteği üzerine kurulmuş, Osmanlı'nın ilk sivil lisesi unvanına sahiptir. İlk olarak Valide Mektebi ve ardından Darülmaarif isimlerini almış, 1911-1933 yılları arasında İnas İdadisi (Erkek Öğretmen Lisesi), 1933-1983 yılları arasında Türkiye'nin ilk kız lisesi İstanbul Kız Lisesi olarak hizmet vermiş, 1983 yılında ise bugünkü hâlini almıştır. Almanca eğitim vermektedir.

Türkiye'de eğitim veren lise türlerinden biri olan Anadolu Liseleri grubuna giren Kabataş Erkek Lisesi, Haydarpaşa Lisesi, Vefa Lisesi ve Pertevniyal Lisesi Türkiye ve dünya çapında tanınmış liselerdendir. İstanbul'da çok sayıda yabancı azınlık bulunmasından dolayı 19. yüzyılda yabancı liselerde artış görülmüştür. Türkiye'nin kurulmasından sonra birçok yabancı okul Türkiye Cumhuriyeti Millî Eğitim Bakanlığı idaresine girmiştir. Fakat bazı liseler hâlen yabancı idaresi altındadır. Özel İtalyan Lisesi, İtalya hükûmeti tarafından yönetilmekte ve İtalyan devlet okulu olarak kabul edilmektedir. Ayrıca finansman ve öğretmen ihtiyacı Başkent Roma'dan sağlanmaktadır. 1863 yılında kurulan Robert Koleji ve diğer birçok okul bunların arasında sayılabilir.

İstanbul da iki tane çok köklü askeri lise bulunmaktadır. Birisi Kuleli Askerî Lisesi olup Çengelköy de bulunmaktadır. İkincisi ise Deniz Lisesi olup Heybeliada da eğitimine devam etmektedir. Ayrıca Hava Harp Okulu ve Deniz Harp Okulu da İstanbul'da bulunmaktadır. Heybeliada da bulunan Deniz Lisesi aynı zamanda Türkiye'nin ilk mühendislik fakültesi olan Mühendishane-i Bahr-i Hümâyun olup 1773 tarihinde Osmanlı'da ilk defa mühendislik alanında açılan yüksek öğretim kurumudur.

İstanbul, çoğu Roma, Bizans ve Osmanlı dönemlerine ait geniş koleksiyonları içeren çok sayıda kütüphaneye sahiptir. Tarihi belge koleksiyonları açısından en önemli kütüphaneler, Topkapı Sarayı Kütüphanesi, İstanbul Arkeoloji Müzeleri Kütüphanesi, Beyazıt Devlet Kütüphanesi, Süleymaniye Kütüphanesi, İstanbul Üniversitesi Kütüphanesi ve İBB'ye bağlı olarak hizmet veren Atatürk Kitaplığı'dır.

\end{document}
```

The last paragraph prints out as

[image]

Then try removing `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` and `\sloppy`.

[image]

The same, but with the addition of `\usepackage{microtype}`

[image]

Note that with the last setting, only five words get hyphenated:

```
adlandırıla-bilecek
bulunmasın-dan
gir-miştir
bulun-maktadır
kütüp-haneler
```

You could make *their* version with no hyphenation and horrible word spacing, and *your* version with hyphenation.

<sub>The text is from the [Istanbul page on Turkish Wikipedia](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0stanbul)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is solved by \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} and \sloppy commands.